# MessageDialog Box in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, messagedialog

I am using MessageDialog  box for popup.but in this it shows only particular meaasge.I want to okcancel buttons with this popup.how to get these buttons.please any one help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you need to add the buttons yourself.

```
var dialog = new MessageDialog("Error. Noooo...");
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK", OnOKButtonClicked));
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel"));

dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Where `OnOKButtonClicked` is a method:

```
private void OnOKButtonClicked(IUICommand command)
{

}
```